# Qt C++ C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Tags: c++, qt

I am aware that this topic has been already discussed, but I have spent half day to figure what i am doing wrong. I keep having this error and I think I've done thousands of syntax checks. Can anyone help me?

```
#ifndef ADDEDITDIALOG_H
#define ADDEDITDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include "characteristics.h"
#include "equipment.h"
#include "generaldata.h"
#include "registration.h"
#include "revisiondialog.h"
#include "vehicle.h"
#include "vehiclehelper.h"
#include "verification.h"
#include "verificationdialog.h"


namespace Ui {
class AddEditDialog;
}

class AddEditDialog : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit AddEditDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
~AddEditDialog();

bool getIsNew() const;
bool getIsEdited() const;
bool getAddRevision() const;

Vehicle getVehicleToAdd() const;

void setVehicleToAdd();
void loadVehicleToEdit(Vehicle car);
void createTableView(const QList<Verification> list);

QList<Verification> getRevisionsList() const;

private slots:
void on_add_revision_clicked();

void on_save_clicked();

void on_cancel_clicked();

void on_generate_reg_number_clicked();

private:
Ui::AddEditDialog *ui;
RevisionDialog *newDialog; //this line is giving the error

Vehicle toAdd;

bool isNew;
bool isEdited;
bool addRevision;

QList<Verification> newVerificationList;
QStandardItemModel *newModel;
};

#endif // ADDEDITDIALOG_H
```

#### revisiondialog.h

```
#ifndef REVISIONDIALOG_H
#define REVISIONDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "addeditdialog.h"
#include "verification.h"

namespace Ui {
class RevisionDialog;
}

class RevisionDialog : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit RevisionDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
~RevisionDialog();

void setRevision();
void setRevisionsList();
Verification getRevision() const;
bool getOk() const;

private slots:
void on_ok_revision_clicked();

void on_cancel_revision_clicked();

private:
Ui::RevisionDialog *ui;
QList<Verification> revisionsList;
Verification revision;
bool okClicked;
};

#endif // REVISIONDIALOG_H
```

Comment: Where is your declaration of `RevisionDialog`?

Comment: @Sir He's already done that.

Comment: Can you post "revisiondialog.h". Can you check in what namespace is? Can you confirm it is included?

Comment: it is commented the line with the error

Comment: Make sure `RevisionDialog` is spelt with the same case in *revisiondialog.h*. Also, check if you forgot to change the `#include` guards for that file, meaning if the include guards in that header are being used in one of the headers included above it, you'd be excluding the contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RevisionDialog` is an undefined type.

I see that you include

```
#include "revisiondialog.h"
```

at the top, which supposedly defines `RevisionDialog`.

However, apparently you managed to create a *circular include dependency*, meaning that your `revisiondialog.h` also includes your `addeditdialog.h` (if that the name of the header that produces the error) either directly or indirectly.

Include guards break the inclusion cycle, resulting in one circular header being physically included first and another being physically included second. In your case `addeditdialog.h` got included first, which is why it knows nothing about the contents of `revisiondialog.h`.

Get rid of circular include dependency. Until you do that, there's no point in trying anything else.

**P.S.** Now, as you posted the contents of `revisiondialog.h` it is obvious that it also includes `addeditdialog.h`. Here's your problem.

Why is your `revisiondialog.h` including `addeditdialog.h`? What is the need for that?

Comment: @AndreyT Thank you! looks like i'we learned something new today!

Comment: @Laszlo Papp: Forward declaration is a solution in situations when circular dependency *between data types* actually exists. In this case there's no circular dependency at all. `addeditdialog.h` was included into `revisiondialog.h` without any reason at all. To fix it, there's no need for any forward declarations. One just has to remove the completely unnecessary `#include` directive.

Answer (score 4):

As it was said, you had included unnecessary header file.
I want to add some thoughts to this matter.

**Do not include headers in your .h file when not necessary.**

**Move them to .cpp file.** You need only QDialog, QStandardItemModel, Vehicle, and Verification, rest can be moved to .cpp file.
It is good habit to minimize possibility of *circular include dependancy*

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
//#include "characteristics.h"
//#include "equipment.h"
//#include "generaldata.h"
//#include "registration.h"
//#include "revisiondialog.h"
#include "vehicle.h"
//#include "vehiclehelper.h"
#include "verification.h"
//#include "verificationdialog.h"
```

For RevisionDialog  use mentioned forward declaration when you use only pointer to class.

```
RevisionDialog *newDialog; // this is only pointer -> no need to include header file
```

**Forward declaration:**

```
namespace Ui {
    class AddEditDialog; // this is forward declaration within Ui namespace
}

class RevisionDialog; // added forward declaration for RevisionDialog *newDialog;

class AddEditDialog : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT
```

When you use **only pointer in header file** it's better to use **forward declaration**